# SilverStripe dynamic ModelAdmin url and title not working

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have created a custom `ModelAdmin` like this:

```
class CompanyAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    // private static $menu_title = 'Companies';
    // private static $url_segment = 'companies';
    private static $managed_models = 'Company';
    private static $menu_icon = 'mysite/images/icons/company-icon.png'; 
}
```

In the above code I have commented out the static properties `$menu_title` and `$url_segment` because I want them to be dynamic (i.e. these properties should be dependent upon the domain name).

For this I created an extension like this:

```
class CompanyMenu extends LeftAndMainExtension {

    public function init() {
        $id = 'Company';
        $title = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "login.example.com" ? "Companies" : "Profile";
        $link =  $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "login.example.com" ? "admin/companies" : "admin/profile";

        CMSMenu::add_menu_item($id, $title, $link);
    }
}
```

In the `_config.php` I added following code to activate the extension:

```
LeftAndMain::add_extension('CompanyMenu');
```

**Problem**

All this code renders the menu in the CMS correctly but:

1. The icon defined in `ModelAdmin` does not come
2. Upon clicking Menu I get "Not Found" popup.

If I uncomment two lines in `CompanyAdmin` and comment the extension code in `_config.php` everything works fine.

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dynamically set the `CompanyAdmin` config settings in your `_config.php` file:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'login.example.com') {
    CompanyAdmin::config()->menu_title = 'Companies';
    CompanyAdmin::config()->url_segment = 'companies';
} else {
    CompanyAdmin::config()->menu_title = 'Profile';
    CompanyAdmin::config()->url_segment = 'profile';
}
```

I would suggest to still set the `$menu_title` and `$url_segment` in the `CompanyAdmin` class so there is a default fallback setting. The config settings will override these:

```
class CompanyAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    private static $menu_title = 'Companies';
    private static $url_segment = 'company';
    private static $managed_models = 'Company';
    private static $menu_icon = 'mysite/images/icons/company-icon.png'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're muddying the waters a bit by extending `LeftAndMainExtension` when you probably don't have to.

Going along with your idea of extending `LeftAndMainExtension`, there's a few things you're missing.

First, your ModelAdmin isn't being used, so the icon and controller are not being picked up from it.

Second, you're missing a block which should look something like this to add an icon to your menu. This is a method on `LeftAndMain` which creates the css to add icons to menu items.

```
public static function menu_icon_for_class($class) {
    $icon = Config::inst()->get($class, 'menu_icon', Config::FIRST_SET);
    if (!empty($icon)) {
        $class = strtolower(Convert::raw2htmlname(str_replace('\\', '-', $class)));
        return ".icon.icon-16.icon-{$class} { background-image: url('{$icon}'); } ";
    }
    return '';
}
```

The CSS returned from this is added to the requirements for the admin area in this line of `LeftAndMain::MainMenu()`

```
if ($menuIconStyling) Requirements::customCSS($menuIconStyling);
```

Regarding the "not found" error you're receiving, it's caused by you not specifying what should happen when the icon is clicked. This is something you need to specify in either `CMSMenu::add_menu_item()` or your `LeftAndMainExtension` depending on how you want to handle it.